# Why doesn't Custom Element work properly on static page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element

(originally from https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/392, moved here)

I'm working on a library (at http://infamous.io, for now at least) in which I'm creating a set of Custom Elements for rendering a 3D scene. The library registers two elements, `[<motor-scene>](https://github.com/infamous/infamous/blob/master/src/motor-html/scene.js)` and [`<motor-node>`](https://github.com/infamous/infamous/blob/master/src/motor-html/node.js). The library depends on [this](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element) `document.registerElement` polyfill for non-supporting browsers.

I have a small problem. Everything works fine when I use the custom elements in the `<body>` of a Meteor app, but when I try doing the exact same thing with a static HTML page and the scripts manually included in the `<head>`, it fails and doesn't work as expected. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong and don't know something about Custom Elements, or if there's a problem with the API.

To see the working demo, just

```
git clone git@github.com:trusktr/site.git
cd site
git checkout infamous-motor-html # it's on this branch.
npm install
meteor # meteor is really easy to install, meteor.com
# visit localhost:3000
```

The result looks like this, the teal and pink elements positioned as expected in 3D space:

[image: working]

Now, if you look in the `public` folder, you'll see the static version in `html-demo.html`. You can open this directly in your browser with `file://`, or visit `localhost:3000/html-demo.html` while running the Meteor app. I have double checked, and I believe that I am doing the same exact thing as in the Meteor version, but I simply cannot get the expected result, and it looks like this:

[image: not-working]

I'm not sure what the problem is, and why it works in the Meteor version (Meteor 1.3 compiles the code with Babel) and doesn't work in the static version (also compiled with Babel via Webpack).

I've added `console.logs` to the `createdCallback`, `attachedCallback`, etc methods in the `registerElement` calls ([for example](https://github.com/infamous/infamous/blob/master/src/motor-html/node.js#L12)). This shows two different orderings of output in the console.

The output for the Meteor version:

[image: meteor-output]

The output for the static version:

[image: static-output]

Could there be a load-order problem? Are there any rules on when `registerElement` should be called? I tried placing the static scripts at the end of the page, which changes the output order, but still renders the same thing (broken, not like the Meteor version).

Any ideas? Is there something about Custom Elements that I don't know? Why does the static example not appear the same as the Meteor example?

Note: I get the same inconsistent behavior between Meteor and static, when using the [WebReflection/document-register-element](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element) polyfill, and when not.

Comment: Please add the information you placed in the GitHub issue here. They may very well delete that issue, and then this question would not make any sense.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks. Updated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Custom Elements work in static pages. In your logs, I can seen that Custom Elements are registered and created so the issue is not related to `registerElement`. You sould try with a simple example.

Comment: @Supersharp I guess they do, but something is different. In Meteor Blaze, the components are added to the page later, dynamically. In the static one, the components exist in the markup when the page is fetched and before the HTML markup is parsed. Perhaps something is happening asynchronously somewhere that I'm racing against, and I haven't found what that is yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If indeed your problem is a race condition between elements being created, then your element may wait until **all** the other elements it depends upon are created/attached.

Then it won't matter the load-order, and you will be able to place your scripts anywhere.

See my answer here: [How to execute a script when the custom element is upgraded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805252/how-to-execute-a-script-when-the-custom-element-is-upgraded/35832956#35832956)

Comment: Thanks@MarcG! In that answer you linked, you use ES6 Class syntax to define your custom elements. How does that work? I thought `document.registerElement` accepts only a name and a prototype, not a class constructor?

Comment: If `CustomX` is your class: `document.registerElement("custom-x", CustomX);`

Comment: Interesting, it works in Chrome with experimental JavaScript enabled (so not ready for production, unless it also works with ES5 constructor pattern). The class `constructor() {}` doesn't get fired though; the browser bypasses that somehow. In my test, it fired the `createdCallback` without firing the `constructor`. The documentation I've found so far shows the method of providing an options object with a `prototype`, and I also read somewhere that classes aren't supported due to how `document.registerElement` works, which is obviously not true anymore. Where is this documented?

Comment: It also appears that `document.registerElement` returns a new constructor which we need to use if we want to make new instances. I assume we can't use our original class constructor? EDIT: Interesting, when I try to use the class directly as in `document.body.appendChild(new CustomX())`, Chrome throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not defined` and the error points to the line with the constructor definition. I ended up using this pattern: http://trusktr.io:7777/eqogedadol.js

Comment: Updated the snippet, we can actually re-assign to the same CustomX identifier, so it's like a higher-order component: http://trusktr.io:7777/ijirusogud

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeet. I just tested, it works with ES5 constructor functions too, no flags necessary. Where'd you find out about this?

Comment: Oh, duuuuuh!!! The `options` parameter has to have the `prototype` property, so, obviously, if we pass a constructor function via the `options` parameter then it will work since the function will have a `prototype` property! Doh!!!

Comment: @trusktr In any case, did you solve your original problem?

Comment: Yes indeed I did. :]