# How to execute a script when the custom element is upgraded

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, html-imports

I have defined a custom element and I want to execute a script only when the custom element is upgraded to its registered type. The use case is that I must call a custom method.

My main html file looks like this:

```
<project-list></project-list>
<script>
    var project_list = document.getElementsByTagName("project-list")[0]
    project_list.custom_method("some_data");
</script>
```

The custom element is registered in a HTML import like this:

```
<script>
  "use strict";
  var currentScript = document._currentScript || document.currentScript;

  class ProjectList extends HTMLElement {

    createdCallback(){
      console.log("created");
    }

    custom_method(data) {
      console.log("custom_method() OK");
      console.log(data);

      this.innerHTML = data;
    }

  }

  document.registerElement("project-list", ProjectList);
</script>
```

My question is simple: **how to make sure the script in the main html file is called only after the custom element gains its `custom_method` method?**

I'm looking for an elegant solution. Something that the spec authors would have thought of. I don't mind changing the architecture quite a bit (for example by moving the javascript from the main file into another custom element if that is necessary).

Comment: on browsers that implement the spec, creating the element and appending it will be sync. in terms of hard-coded tags though, afaik, there is no "allComponentsReady"-like DOM event. one way is to raise a custom event on `document` from within the component, and use that event like an `onload()` event for the page's code that needs the custom methods. you might also look into something like redux to wire up many disparate web components and app methods in a way that doesn't suck.

Comment: @dandavis: This is what I do. But I also set a flag. If the flag is set, then the component is already set up and the custom method can be executed immediately. Otherwise, it is scheduled for when the event fires. I have posted an answer with the code I use.

Comment: @dandavis: To wire up many disparate web components: If some webcomponent depends on others, then it must wait until ALL these other components are ready, before it set/dispatches its own flags/events.

Comment: of course, you can wait on about anything with a self-defer pattern: `(function wait(){if(! project_list.custom_method) return setTimeout(wait, 50);  project_list.custom_method("some_data");}());` you can white-list more pre-reqs in there if you need several depends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sync HTML Import**

As suggested by @dandavis, because of the `sync` default behaviour of the `<link>` and `<script>` elements, you just have to put your tags in the right order: registration before method call.

Or instead you can call your custom method when the `DOMContentLoaded` or the `window.onload` event is fired, as below:

```js
window.onload = function() 
{
    var project_list = document.getElementsByTagName("project-list")[0]
    project_list.custom_method("some_data")     
}
```

```html
<project-list></project-list>

<script>
  "use strict";
  var currentScript = document._currentScript || document.currentScript;

  class ProjectList extends HTMLElement {

    createdCallback(){
      console.log("created");
    }

    custom_method(data) {
      console.log("custom_method() OK");
      console.log(data);

      this.innerHTML = data;
    }

  }

  document.registerElement("project-list", ProjectList);
</script>
```

**Async HTML Import**

If for some reasons you want to load your HTML Import file asynchronousely, you can wait for the `link.onload` event. At this time the |`<script>` inside the import has been already exectued, the custom element registered and created.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="import" href="projectList.html" id="projectList" async>
    <script>
    projectList.onload = function ()
    {
      console.log( "import {loaded}" )
      var project_list = document.getElementsByTagName( "project-list" )[0]
      project_list.custom_method("some_data")
    } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <project-list id="pl"></project-list>
    <script>
        console.warn( "custom_method is " + pl.custom_method ) //undefined
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**With WebComponents.js polyfill**

In this situation the polyfill won't instantiate the created object immediately after the import is loaded. Instead you should listen to the `WebComponentsReady` event:

```
document.addEventListener( "WebComponentsReady", function ()
{
    console.log( "WebComponentsReady" )
    var project_list = document.getElementsByTagName( "project-list" )[0]
    project_list.custom_method( "some_data" )
} )
```

It works with Firefox, IE 11, and also with Chrome.

Comment: This would work on Chrome but on Firefox with the Polymer polyfill, it won't work. It is always asynchronous

Comment: I think this is related to this bug: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/431

Comment: For a cross-browser solution I've updated my answer.

Comment: @user6020072: That bug says it should NOT block on async.  HTML imports, as per spec, may be sync or async. Read here: http://webcomponents.org/articles/introduction-to-html-imports/

Comment: This also works: `HTMLImports.whenReady(function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Load the dependency via an `import` in your custom element module. For example, a custom element module (e.g.`something.mjs`) which depends on Highcharts:

```
import '/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js'

class Something extends HTMLElement {}

customElements.define('x-something', Something)
```