# What is the difference between `HTMLImports.whenReady` and `window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {`

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, custom-element, html-imports

What is the difference between `HTMLImports.whenReady`  and `window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {`?

[Polymer's official documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#main-document-definitions) says:

> "To define an element in your main HTML document, define the element from HTMLImports.whenReady(callback). callback is invoked when all imports in the document have finished loading."

[Webcomponents.org's official documentation on imports](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/) says:

> Under native imports,  tags in the main document block the loading of imports. This is to ensure the imports have loaded and any registered elements in them have been upgraded. This native behavior is difficult to polyfill so the HTML Imports polyfill doesn't try. Instead the WebComponentsReady event is a stand in for this behavior:

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5):

They are *almost* * the same: both are triggered at the same time.

So you can choose your favourite flavor between `callback` and `Event`.

*Nota Bene*: if, for some reasons, you reference the `CustomElement.js` polyfill alone (i.e. without the `HTMLImports.js` feature), only the `WebComponentsReady` event will be thrown.

(I prefer to use the `Event Handler` because in the first case you need to be sure the `HTMLImports` is defined, and because it is the only documented API [here](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/))

---

*: Of course they are different! The difference is stated in the quoted definitions.

- The latter is waiting for the Custom Elements to be instanciated. It is triggered by `CustomElement.js` polyfill.
- The first is waiting only for the Imports to be loaded and parsed. It is called by `HTMLImports.js` polyfill, just after `{HTMLImportsLoaded}` has been sent.

However in normal situation, because Custom Elements are instanciated as soon as they are registered, the 2 events will happen one after the other.

**Chronological order**

1. `<link rel=import>.onload()`,
2. `{HTMLImportsLoaded}` event,
3. `HTMLImports.whenReady()`
4. `{WebComponentsReady}` event

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35808305/4600982).

Comment: I think the formulation "[WebComponentsReady]...waiting for Custom Elements to be instantiated" is misleading, doesn't it rather signal that the webcomponents APIs are ready? In chronological order, WebComponentsReady can precede HTMLImportsLoaded. (depends on webcomponents polyfill version, 1.x included HTML imports, 2.x doesn't, native in Chrome between 2014 and 2019)