# dom-if can't use a function as the "if" value in firefox

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

code like the below works fine in chrome but in firefox I get the following error when using polymer 1.9.1

[undefined::_annotatedComputationEffect]: compute method `hasMoreData` not defined

```
<template>


    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[sections]]">
        <div>
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{hasMoreData(item)}}">
                <div name="loadMore">load more</div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </template>
</template> 
<script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
            is: 'listing-collection',
            //...other stuff...
            hasMoreData: function(item) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is really frustrating that something basic doesn't seem to work the way the documentation says in a particular modern browser and works fine in another. :( stuff like this makes me nervous about using polymer in production. I have faced other cross-browser issues but worked around them, but this time I think the framework has finally pushed me over the edge :)

Comment: you use two scopes so you can't get this function. Try to send it like a prop from repeat template like items

Comment: thank you for replying. could you show me an example in code of what you mean by "send it like a prop from repeat template like items"?

Comment: l'm sorry cause it's my mistake. l checked your approach and it works fine if we use it without `HTMLImports.whenReady` callback cause it fired before `webcomponents` are ready. [Read more about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017594/what-is-the-difference-between-htmlimports-whenready-and-window-addeventliste)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. unfortunately it did not work for me. what did seem to work in all the browsers that I tested was to move the conditional piece of UI to its own component, pass it a reference to the section through its attribute, and then use dom-if in there. what on earth? I am sorry but this is nonsense and makes me regret my choice of framework. :( how hard can it be to get an "if" to work? thank you again for your help, though, as your first suggestion did give me an idea on how to get myself unstuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what I ended up having to do was move the conditional "load more" to its own component like so

```
<load-more section="[[item]]"></load-more>
```

and then use dom-if in the component like this

```
<dom-module id="load-more">
    <template>
        <template is="dom-if" if="[[hasMoreData(section)]]">
            load more
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
            Polymer({
                is: 'load-more',
                properties: {
                    section: {
                        value: {},
                        type: Object
                    }
                },
                hasMoreData: function (section) {
                    return section.Listings.length > 0 && section.Listings.length < section.Filter.Count;
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

why should I have to do this? why does it work the simpler way in chrome and not firefox?

who knows, but I've had too many of these kind of weird issues with polymer for it to be a coincidence.

sorry, google, I really wanted to like Polymer but I am starting to regret choosing it. everything has a learning curve but too many things work fine in one browser, completely fail in another, or have weird corner cases you trigger by just trying to use the framework as shown in the documentation, some of which is incorrect or out of date.

I think web components have heaps of potential, but Polymer, at least the version I am using, is not a good advertisement for web components.

unfortunately, this diagram about angular might as well apply to polymer too, and I have to agree with [this guy's feelings about polymer](https://www.reddit.com/r/PolymerJS/comments/4odkw6/rant_seriously_pissed_off_with_polymer/).

[image]

I will try to make it work for my current project as I have probably gone too far down this rabbit hole to change my choice of technology now, but if things keep going the way they have been, I have a feeling I will avoid polymer wherever possible.