# Cannot call Webcomponent method from page

Tags: javascript, web-component

I try to make a simple webcomponent (with webcomponents.js v 0.7.23). This component has a method (`setTitre()`).
If I call this method in my HTML page at startup, Chrome is ok but FF and IE say that the function is undefined.
If I call this method from the console (`document.querySelector('hello-world').setWho('new')`), it's ok in all browsers.

Code is here : https://github.com/olofweb/Webcomponents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a script when the custom element is upgraded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805252/how-to-execute-a-script-when-the-custom-element-is-upgraded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the *webcomponentsjs* polyfill, you need to wait for the `WebComponentsReady` event before calling a custom element method:

```
document.addEventListener( 'WebComponentsReady', function () 
{
    document.querySelector('hello-world').setTitre()
} )
```

It's due to the asynchronous upgrading of the custom elements when using the non-native implementation.